# Retrieve information from csv file

Tags: python-3.x

`[Id, Name, Email]
[1, Kevin, kevin@mail.com]
[2, bob, bob@mail.com]
[3, Kevin, k7iv.mail.com]`

*This data is present in info.csv

If Id and name is known, extract mail from respective row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("myfile.csv", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    i = line.split(',')[0].strip()
    n = line.split(',')[1].strip()
    e = line.split(',')[2].strip()

    if i == '2':
        print("Email :", e)

    if n == "Kevin" and i == '3':
        print("Email : ", e)
```